# What cause : Is a directory error

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to execute the following unix shell:

```
pathFile=$1
ROOT_PATH=`/main/prj/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/mainElab_0.1`

echo "Directory File Input: $1"

java -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -cp .:$ROOT_PATH:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/routines.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/external_sort.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc41.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/talend_file_enhanced_20070724.jar:$ROOT_PATH/../lib/talendcsv.jar:$ROOT_PATH/mainelab_0_1.jar:$ROOT_PATH/subload_0_1.jar:$ROOT_PATH/subload_0_1.jar:$ROOT_PATH/suboutput_0_1.jar: alf.mainelab_0_1.mainElab -context_param dirPath=$1 "$@"
```

but I am getting the error /main/prj/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/mainElab_0.1 : Is a directory.

Error: Could not find or load main class alf.mainelab_0_1.mainElab

I am passing correctly parameter $1 from another shell.

Does anyone could help me find out what's wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `ROOT_PATH="/main...."` not backticks.

Comment: Thank you! I also changed the -cp .:$ROOT_PATH:$ROOT_PATH as -cp $ROOT_PATH